# Python DataNitro - "CellRange set to object of wrong length"

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting, excel-2010, datanitro

I am trying to concatenate two columns in Excel 2010 using DataNitro, but whenever I try to run this command,

```
CellRange("C1:C5").value = CellRange("A1:A5").value + CellRange("B1:B5").value
```

I get this error in the DataNitro Python Shell - "CellRange set to object of wrong length"

I am trying to concatenate values in columns A and B into column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CellRange("A1:A5").value + CellRange("B1:B5").value
```

Will add together two lists of length 5 to give you a list of length 10. To concatenate the elements in the lists, you should do:

```
CellRange("C1:C5").value = [x + y for x, y in zip(CellRange("A1:A5").value, CellRange("B1:B5").value)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben :) I was going through your video and thought of trying Data Nitro for concatenating 3 columns of 6, 8, 8 rows respectively, and I would like to generate all the possible combinations from those 3 columns, I will post this query in a separate section if I get stuck somewhere. 

Once again, thanks a lot! you rock!!